# Calculate current balance of account in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to complete this task in Python.

You will be given a sample CSV file that contains a list of transactions.

- The first column is the   account number of the person the money is from,
- The second column is the amount of money, and
- The third column is the account number of the person the money is to.

Your task is to parse the CSV, and calculate the current balance of every account number.

Submit a python script that accepts a single argument (the location of the transactions CSV file), and prints out the balance of every account.

**CSV file pattern:**

```
from, amount, to
314, 470.21, 275
12, 1788.98, 149
316, 2949.53, 314
5, 2193.48, 454
314, 1402.76, 371
82, 1212.1, 4420
```

I rendered this CSV file with following code:

```
import csv

def csv_data(path):
    with open(path) as csv_file:
        readCSV = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        for line in readCSV:
            col_from = line['from']
            col_to = line['to']
            col_amount = line['amount']
            print(col_from, col_amount, col_to)

csv_data('transactions.csv')
```

How can I calculate the current balance of every account?

Every account made multiple transactions.

For example: If account number 314 is in the `from` column it sends the given amount to the account number in the `to`column. When this account number is found in the `from` column the previous balance must be added.

How can I do these calculations in a `for` loop?

Comment: Looks too much like homework.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an ideal answer but you can use `pandas` for this.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/the/file')
total_for_each_account = [df[df['from'] == account]['amount'].sum() for account in df.from.unique()]
```

returns a list of the sum for each unique account present in `from` column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas as suggested by @MrPyCharm. If you need just clear-python solution wuthout extra dependencies you can do this like that:

```
data = [
    [314, 470.21,  275],
    [12,  1788.98, 149],
    [316, 2949.53, 314],
    [5,  2193.48, 454],
    [314, 1402.76, 371],
    [82, 1212.1,  420],
]

balances = {}
for from_, value, to_ in data:
    balances[from_]  = - value + balances.get(from_, 0) 
    balances[to_]  = value + balances.get(to_, 0) 

for user_id, balance in balances.items():
    print('Id: {}, balance: {}'.format(user_id, balance))
```

Output:

```
Id: 314, balance: 1076.5600000000002
Id: 275, balance: 470.21
Id: 12, balance: -1788.98
Id: 149, balance: 1788.98
Id: 316, balance: -2949.53
Id: 5, balance: -2193.48
Id: 454, balance: 2193.48
Id: 371, balance: 1402.76
Id: 82, balance: -1212.1
Id: 420, balance: 1212.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for this, where the key represents the account number.

```
import csv

def csv_data(path):

    accounts = {}  # storage of the account balances

    with open(path) as csv_file:
        readCSV = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        for line in readCSV:
            account_from = int(line['from'])
            account_to = int(line['to'])
            transaction_amount = float(line['amount'])

            # subtract from old account
            if account_from in accounts:
                accounts[account_from] -= transaction_amount
            else:
                accounts[account_from] = (0-transaction_amount)

             # add to new account
             if account_to in accounts:
                accounts[account_to] += transaction_amount
             else:
                accounts[account_to] = transaction_amount

    for account in accounts:
        print("{}: \t{}".format(account, accounts[account]))

csv_data('transactions.csv')
```

Which gives following Output:

```
420:    1212.1
5:      -2193.48
454:    2193.48
371:    1402.76
12:     -1788.98
82:     -1212.1
275:    470.21
149:    1788.98
314:    1076.56
316:    -2949.53
```

Please be aware that transactions should always follow the [ACID-Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Comment: thanks.one more thing how can count total transactions of each account no ?

Comment: Instead of just saving the account balance, I would store a dict for every account which stores balance and transaction count: 
`accounts[account_to] = {'balance': transaction_amount, 'transaction_count': 1}` Then increase the transaction count every time you perform a transaction.